# Resuable markup fragments with Asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoctor

I am writing a guide in Asciidoctor for our company. In this guide I would like to define resuable markup fragments which I can use in the document like this one:

```
:MUST: [small]#Must#
```

Although the content is verbatim copied to the resulting document. Does anyone know how to define resuable markup snippets with Asciidoctor?

Answer (score 1):

- Includes are the easiest way to reuse content
- Macro is an other solution, but this requires some code.

I think that my answer to "[how to define own asciidoc macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37397532)" also answer your question.