# use of roles in asciidoctor macros?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm trying to create a simple macro to render a text item in red in `asciidoctor`.
The following does not work:

```
:redtext: [red]#some important text in red that occurs a lot#

{redtext}
```

or for an even simpler example:

```
:redcross: [red]#&#x2718;#
```

I am not clear on the rules for what can and cannot be substituted by a macro. The `asciidoctor` manual has a blank space for macros at present (http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#macros). The `asciidoc` manual (http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/chunked/ch21.html) isn't that clear either but may not apply to `asciidoctor` anyway.

A related unanswered question is [Resuable markup fragments with Asciidoctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38042386/resuable-markup-fragments-with-asciidoctor).
A related question to that suggests using includes which is overkill for this.

What are the limitations of macros?

Answer (score 1):

What you have defined is not a macro, it's an attribute. (When you use it, it's called an attribute reference).

You can perform substitution eagerly in the definition of an attribute using the inline pass macro. In the target position, it accepts a comma-separated list of substitution names (or substitution letters).

In your case, you can write:

```
:redtext: pass:q[[red]#some important text in red that occurs a lot#]
```

The relevant part is:

```
pass:q[...]
```

See [substitutions in an attribute entry](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#substitutions-in-an-attribute-entry) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think includes work well enough. We have a single `glossary.asciidoc` file to contain all the re-usable snippets, for example:

```
tag::redtext[]
[red]#some important text in red that occurs a lot#
end::redtext[]
```

In `index.asciidoc` you can add a little helper:

```
:g: glossary.asciidoc
```

Then wherever you need this snippet:

```
include::{g}[tag=redtext]
```

Comment: That introduces several new problems:
* The include can only be used at the start of the line
* Your document is no longer a single source file
* The include is almost as verbose as the text I want to include.